# Cambiar el valor inicial a un espacio en blanco

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Deseo Cambiar el valor inicial el cual el 0 a un espacio en blanco he tratado con diferentes tipos de datos pero me aparece 0.

Este es el codigo

```
    const total = Inmuebles.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.Price, 0);
    
    const discount = Inmuebles.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + ((item.Discount || 0) / 100) * item.Price,
        0,
      );
```

Esto es el codigo a Renderizar

```
                    <dl>
                      <dt>Valor Total UF</dt>
                      <dd>
                        <b>
                          <FormattedNumber value={total} />
                        </b>
                      </dd>
                      <dt>Total Descuentos UF</dt>
                      <dd>
                        <b>
                          {discount > 0 && `-`}
                          <FormattedNumber value={discount} />
                        </b>
                      </dd>
                      <dt>
                        <b>Valor Final UF</b>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                        <b>
                          <FormattedNumber value={total - discount} />
                        </b>
                      </dd>
                    </dl>
```

y finalmente esta es la imagen renderizada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que quieres es que si el total o el discount son 0, no se renderizen como 0 sino como un espacio vacio (o sea que no salga nada)?

Comment: si Pipe es lo solicitado ya que pues a peticion de cliente es asi aunque a modo de experiencia me parece que es mejor dejar el valor inicial

Comment: y porque no haces eso al renderizar en pantalla... algo como `{ discount ? <FormattedNumber value={discount} /> : null }` ? asi si hay algo lo muestras, sino no renderizas nada

Comment: mil gracias pipe realmente no se me ocurrio estaba pegado en la variable y ver de donde venia todo ya que apenas llevo pocos dias en el proyecto pero de verdad mil gracias